# Which tree type used in java 8 HashMap bucket?

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8

As I know in java8 HashMap bucket implementation was changed a bit. If bucket size exceeds some value then list transforms to the "balanced tree".

I don't understand
1. what type of balanced tree used in Oracle JDK?  (AVL? red-black? something like in databases for indexes?)
2. Is it binary tree?
3. As I understand sorting executes according hashcode. For example in my bucket I have 102 elements. 100 values with hashcode equally 12 (I understand that it worth but I just need to understand this behaviour) and 2 with hashcode 22.
How does search will be executed for value ?

[image]

Comment: Note that you shouldn't be relying on this behavior. It is an implementation-specific fallback in case code already has broken behavior (clustered hashcodes). And if your keys don't hash well but are comparable you could also use a treemap from the start.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the implementation, it looks like a binary tree. More specifically, the comment below suggests it's a red-black tree :

```
static final class TreeNode<K,V> extends LinkedHashMap.Entry<K,V> {
    TreeNode<K,V> parent;  // red-black tree links
    TreeNode<K,V> left;
    TreeNode<K,V> right;
    TreeNode<K,V> prev;    // needed to unlink next upon deletion
    boolean red;
    ...
}
```

As for handling equal hash codes, this is addressed in the Javadoc :

> Tree bins (i.e., bins whose elements are all TreeNodes) are
>   ordered primarily by hashCode, but in the case of ties, if two
>   elements are of the same "`class C implements Comparable<C>`",
>   type then their compareTo method is used for ordering.

The `TreeNode`s used in `HashMap` are said to be structured similarly to those of `TreeMap`.

You can see the implementation of the search for a `TreeNode` containing the required key here :

```
    /**
     * Finds the node starting at root p with the given hash and key.
     * The kc argument caches comparableClassFor(key) upon first use
     * comparing keys.
     */
    final TreeNode<K,V> find(int h, Object k, Class<?> kc) {
        TreeNode<K,V> p = this;
        do {
            int ph, dir; K pk;
            TreeNode<K,V> pl = p.left, pr = p.right, q;
            if ((ph = p.hash) > h)
                p = pl;
            else if (ph < h)
                p = pr;
            else if ((pk = p.key) == k || (k != null && k.equals(pk)))
                return p;
            else if (pl == null)
                p = pr;
            else if (pr == null)
                p = pl;
            else if ((kc != null ||
                      (kc = comparableClassFor(k)) != null) &&
                     (dir = compareComparables(kc, k, pk)) != 0)
                p = (dir < 0) ? pl : pr;
            else if ((q = pr.find(h, k, kc)) != null)
                return q;
            else
                p = pl;
        } while (p != null);
        return null;
    }
```

As you can see, this is similar to the standard binary search tree search. First they search for a `TreeNode` having the same `hashCode` as the searched key (since a single bucket of a `HashMap` may contain entries having different `hashCode`s). Then it proceeds until a `TreeNode` having a key equal to the required key is found. The secondary search uses `compareTo` if the class of the key implements `Comparable`. Otherwise, a more exhaustive search is performed.

Comment: but if **compareTo** is not implemented?

Comment: If JDK already has TreeMap what the reason to create same class with another name?

Comment: @gstackoverflow It's not the same class. The `TreeNode` used in HashMap is an implementation detail. It is supposed to give better performance than the original linked-list implementation of a single bin of the HashMap when the number of entries in a single bin exceeds some threshold.

Comment: I understand this. My question a bit different. Why can't jdk founders to use TreeMap instead of TreNode inside HashMap?

Comment: @gstackoverflow If compareTo is not implemented, a more costly search is performed until the entry containing the required key is found.

Comment: smth like Search in width / depth ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow I guess they considered it and determined an internal implementation would be more efficient.

Comment: @gstackoverflow You can look at the code yourself. There's a `find(int h, Object k, Class<?> kc)` method that looks for a TreeNode having the passed hashCode (h) and whose key is equal to k. If it reaches a TreeNode whose hash code is the required value but the key is not equal, it either uses compareTo if available or searches for the key recursively in the right sub-tree, and if not found searches in the left sub-tree.